# Force a Dask Delayed object to compute all parameters before applying the function

Tags: python, dask

I am really enjoying using Dask.

Is there a way that I can force a Delayed object to require all it's arguments to be computed before applying the delayed function?

easy example (the use-case is more interesting with a collection):

```
def inc(x, y):
    return x + y

dinc = dask.delayed(inc, pure=True)
```

to something like

```
def inc(x, y):
    if hasattr(x, compute):
        x = x.compute()
    if hasattr(y, compute):
        y = y.compute()
    return x + y

dinc = dask.delayed(inc, pure=True)
```

In this way the function will act according to a reduce pattern.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dask.delayed automatically does this.  Any `delayed` object or dask collection (array, dataframe, bag) will be computed before they enter the delayed function.

Comment: Hi and thanks! for the answer! It actually works! My bad was not delaying inc and using just "inc" itself.